# How does a forward lifting surface affect ideal lift distribution of a main wing?

Tags: lift, drag

In Peter K's answer to this [elliptical wing with lowest drag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31996/why-does-the-elliptical-wing-have-the-lowest-drag/31998#31998) question the minimum induced drag lift distribution for a wing is described as one with a constant downwash angle across its span. When a forward lifting surface is involved, as with a three surface aircraft, it creates its own downwash across its span and upwash beyond the tips. Both impinge on the larger main wing.

Is the combined minimum induced drag for both lifting surfaces still one where the main wing downwash angle is constant across its span?

Comment: Maybe the following is helpful – [PK](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21329/14897): *The strength of these induced speeds varies with speed, so the main wing can produce an elliptic circulation at only one angle of attack.*

Comment: @ymb1 That implies that the efficiency of the combined wing is evaluated in the same way as an isolated main wing, which would mean the answer to the above is yes.