# How does a transonic aircraft gains longitudinal stability

Tags: aerodynamics, stability

How is the transonic aircraft lift augmentation help in achieving stability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is an aircraft designed to be longitudinally stable?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82791/how-is-an-aircraft-designed-to-be-longitudinally-stable) If not, please tell us exactly what extra information you're looking for that isn't already covered in your previous question.

Comment: I second @Pondlife, I bet there is a good question in the making here, just needs to be set up more specifically. What is it you do not understand in the longitudinal stability at transsonic speed?

Comment: I would like to know how is it achieved?